# Fingerprint driver not detected on Asus Vivobook X512FL

Tags: drivers, touchpad, asus, scanner

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus Vivobook X512FL and it has a embedded fingerprint scanner on the touchpad and it works fine with windows 10 but it is not detected in ubuntu

Here is output `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56dd IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation BayHubTech Integrated SD controller (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9da8 (rev 30)
00:1e.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9daa (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSD 660P Series (rev 03)
```

Output of `cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i "Mouse\|Touchpad"` is:

```
N: Name="ELAN1300:00 04F3:3087 Mouse"
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
N: Name="ELAN1300:00 04F3:3087 Touchpad"
H: Handlers=mouse1 event6 `
```

Output of `xinput list | grep -i "Mouse\|Touchpad"` is :

```
⎜   ↳ ELAN1300:00 04F3:3087 Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1300:00 04F3:3087 Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Comment: Based on a bit of research, the fingerprint sensor device is a `04f3:0903` from Elan Microelectronics. Unfortunately, [the device does not appear to be compatible with any version of Linux](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:04f3-0903) at this time 

Comment: fingerprint sensor device is `04F3:3087`,  please check for this one